# Dynamically change jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate an element from variable in `jquery`. My variable is like below:

```
var panelheader = "<div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading pnlbld'>Test</div><div class='panel-body'></div></div>"
```

I want to change `panel-heading` text and want to insert in `panel-body`.

```
$(panelheader + '.panel-heading').text('Name')
```

Above statement removes all `divs` inside panel with text `Name`. But I want this as `panel-heading`.

Also, when I tried to insert `table` between `panel-body` like below:

```
$(panelheader + '.panel-body').prepend(mytbl)
```

It creates `table` before `panel-heading`.

I want the "Name" to be in the place of "Test" and `mytbl` in between

```
<div class='panel-body'></div>
```

Comment: `$(panelheader).find('.panel-heading').text('Name')` and same for `panel-body`

Comment: In addition to the above you need to do `$(panelheader).find('.panel-body').html(myTbl)` to put your table as the content of `panel-body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the HTML string in `panel-header` into DOM elements, and then do the replacement in that.

```
var ph = $(panelheader);
ph.find(".panel-heading").text('Name');
$("#somediv").append(ph);
```